# How to create passwordalias for payara inside docker

Tags: docker, glassfish, payara

I'd like to deploy my JakartaEE application with Docker (compose). (Imagetag 6.2023.12-jdk17)
This works fine. I can create the jdbc connection pool with pre-boot-commands.
For this pool I'd like to create a passwordalias with a passwordfile.
I copy the passwordfile with docker-secrets inside the container.

But it fails in the pre-boot-commands.
How can I create the passwordalias?

Adding --passwordfile=/run/secrets/payaramysqlsecret to pre-boot-commands -> fails with Command lookup failed
Added it in combination with create-password-alias -> same failure because --passwordfile is an option for asadmin-command
How can I specify asadmin-options in .asadmin file (like pre-boot-commands)?
I found this sentence 'If necessary, also specify any asadmin utility options that are required to enable subcommands in the file to run.' in an older documentation at oracle - so it should be possible.